# Resolve a promise after component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

Following problem is related to setting the state with most up to date props, after a promise resolves.

Problem Statement:
The following method gets called upon a submit button click.

```
handleClickSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true, errorMessage: ''});

    const {orderID, addAttachments} = this.props;
    const {attachedFiles} = this.state;

    let currentAttachment = 0;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('order_id', orderID);
    formData.append('attachment_type_id', selectedAttachmentTypeID);

    // make one request for each file
    attachedFiles.forEach(attachment => {
      formData.set('file', attachment);

/** this method dispatches an action which updates props **/ 
      addAttachments(formData)
        .then(() => {
         /**if there is an error with attachment update 
* attachmentFailure within state, else update successfulUploads
*/
          this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {

           return (prevProps.attachmentError
              ? {
                attachmentFailures: [
                  ...prevState.attachmentFailures,
                  attachment.name
                ]
              }
              : {successfulUploads: prevState.successfulUploads + 1});
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            loading: false,
            attachmentFailures: [
              ...prevState.attachmentFailures,
              attachment.name
            ]
          }));
          this.closeModal();
        })
        .then(() => {
          currentAttachment++;

          // on the last attachment in the loop kill the loading spinner
          if (currentAttachment === attachedFiles.length) {
            this.setState({
              loading: false,
              isToastOpen: true,
              toastMessage:
                this.state.attachmentFailures.length > 0
                  ? this.getErrorMessage()
                  : `${
                      this.state.successfulUploads
                    } Attachments uploaded successfully`
            });
            console.log(this.state);
            this.closeModal();
          }
        });
    });
  };
```

Now my question is, when the `addAttachment()` method dispatches an action to update the redux store then, I am not sure if the prop is updating first, or the promise is resolving first. If the promise resolves first, we are now in the `.then()` block, and `prevProps.attachmentError` might not be updated in redux, so maybe the prop isn't up to date?

And if the above statement is correct then how should I update the state within `.then()` with most up to date props?

Comment: `or the promise is resolving first` - which one? the one returned by `addAttachments`? in the `.then` is called when that's resolved

Comment: the first ```.then()``` block.

Comment: yes, and as I already said, the promise returned by `addAttachments` would of course be resolved before that .then is called

Comment: ok.. (apologies in advance if its a noob question since I am new to redux world)

so that means the props will be updated by action dispatch first and then the control will return to ```.then()``` block.

Comment: I don't know, because I can't see what `addAttachments` does, nor when it resolves the Promise it returns ... if the promise returned by `addAttachments` is resolved once *props are updated by action dispatch*, then yes of course, the `.then` will be executed after this occurs